# Enterprise architect no longer sync to current project

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

For some unknown reason, my Enterprise Architect suddenly stopped syncing project to the current version. We use Apache Subversion. I have working directory, that according to SVN is synced to the latest revision. When I open project in EA and click on get latest, nothing happens, even though I'm 100% sure I should get few more diagrams.

Any idea how to fix this? I know this is very vague description, but that's all I got.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get more info what EA thinks of a controlled package status.

It decides it based on last load / last saved dates stored both in project file and in the XML file of the controlled package. You can see dates stored in the project in Package Control->Configure dialog.

First attempt to fix it would be this: In package control context menu, select "Re-synch status with VC provider". It should copy SVN status to status of EA controlled package. Check the system output window for any messages.

And of course, EA is not syncing controlled packages to actual version by itself - that's done by selection of "Get Latest.../ Get All Latest..." menu item. And the package has to be VC-controlled, but that's probably clear.